# Renaming multiple numbered files

Tags: python, file, pandas

I have a series of data from one of my data loggers and it saves them sequentially:

```
data_0, data_1, ... , data_10, data_11,.., data_100, data_101
```

and so on.

I was importing the files one by one in pandas and processing them, later realizing that the file sequence that pandas is importing is:

```
data_0, data_1, data_100, data_101,..., data_109, data_11, data_110,
```

Which is messing up my calculations like crazy.

The code I am using is

```
path = 'C:/Users/XXX/Documents/test1/XYZ'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.dat")
for file_ in allFiles:
    data = pd.read_table(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
```

I am opening to renaming the files to `data_xxx.dat` format or any other way to import files which work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your file-names are being returned sorted, which for strings uses lexicographic ordering (the normal ordering for strings).

```
In [23]: x = ['data_0', 'data_1', 'data_100', 'data_101', 'data_109', 'data_11', 'data_110']

In [24]: sorted(x)
Out[24]: ['data_0', 'data_1', 'data_100', 'data_101', 'data_109', 'data_11', 'data_110']
```

See, it is sorted. A quick fix is to sort your list of file names using a `key` function forcing it to order by `int` ordering. 
Something like this:

```
In [25]: sorted(x, key=lambda s: int(s.partition('_')[-1]))
Out[25]: ['data_0', 'data_1', 'data_11', 'data_100', 'data_101', 'data_109', 'data_110']
```

Really, you should have used `.zfill` when you saved your file-names, which would make lexicograhic ordering behave as you would like:

```
In [28]: x = ["".join([a,b,c.zfill(5)]) for a,b,c in (s.partition('_') for s in x)]

In [29]: x
Out[29]:
['data_00000',
 'data_00001',
 'data_00100',
 'data_00101',
 'data_00109',
 'data_00011',
 'data_00110']

In [30]: sorted(x)
Out[30]:
['data_00000',
 'data_00001',
 'data_00011',
 'data_00100',
 'data_00101',
 'data_00109',
 'data_00110']

In [31]:
```

Using `zfill` is the best approach if you can give some sort of upper bound to the number of files you expect to have.

In case it isn't obvious what `zfill` is doing;

```
In [31]: "3".zfill(3)
Out[31]: '003'

In [32]: "3".zfill(2)
Out[32]: '03'

In [33]: "3".zfill(1)
Out[33]: '3'

In [34]: "3".zfill(10)
Out[34]: '0000000003'
```

Comment: Beautiful!! :-)

Comment: 1) I dont have any control over the saved file naming criteria from the data logger.
<br /> 2) My files have .dat extension at the end, so ended up getting error for expected int and received 0.dat when using 
<br /> "sorted(x, key=lambda s: int(s.partition('_')[-1]))"

Comment: @ParthSingh OK, well, it seems you have the tools necessary to deal with this issue, no?

Comment: No, it didn't solve the issue. sorry.
I tried making a a string list sorted and passing it through, with


for num in range (0,399):
    file_ = glob.glob(path+"data_"+str(num)+".dat")
    portfolio = pd.read_table(file_,index_col=None, header=0)

but, got this error

IOError: Expected file path name or file-like object, got <type 'list'> type

Comment: No, I meant you can *easily* extend the above to fit your situation where the file ends with `.dat`...

Comment: @ParthSingh so just use `lambda s: int(s.partition('_')[-1].partition('.')[0])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga got an IO error "<lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: @ParthSingh how are you using the function??? Here, just use `sorted(x, key=lambda s: int(s.rstrip('.dat').partition('_')[-1]))`. It's cleaner anyway. In the future, instead of just copying and pasting an answer, you should try to *understand*  what the answer is doing, and you could have written that yourself...

Comment: Can you explain what this is doing? I get the part of the rstrip but not understanding the partition [-1] part

Comment: @ParthSingh see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition). It works like `str.split` except it only uses the first instance of the separator, *partitioning* the string into a 3-tuple: `(before, sep, after)`